# is it possible to override built-in Ruby methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a problem where I have to pass an rpsec test. The problem is that the method is using the same name as a built in ruby method `.count`

given that I cannot change the rspec test, is it possible to override `.count` to behave differently? if not, is there a better way to get around this?

here is the rspec test I am trying to pass

```
subject = FinancialSummary.one_day(user: user, currency: :usd)
expect(subject.count(:deposit)).to eq(2)
```

my code:

```
class FinancialSummary

  def self.one_day(user: user, currency: currency)
    one_day_range = Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day
    find_transaction(user.id, currency).where(created_at: one_day_range)
  end

  def self.find_transaction(user_id, currency)
    Transaction.where(user_id: user_id,
                      amount_currency: currency.to_s.upcase
                      )
  end
end
```

output:

```
    [#<Transaction:0x00007f9b39c2e9b8
      id: 1,
      user_id: 1,
      amount_cents: 1,
      amount_currency: "USD",
      category: "deposit",
      created_at: Sat, 10 Mar 2018 18:46:53 UTC +00:00,
      updated_at: Sat, 10 Mar 2018 18:46:53 UTC +00:00>,
     #<Transaction:0x00007f9b3d0dbc38
      id: 2,
      user_id: 1,
      amount_cents: 2000,
      amount_currency: "USD",
      category: "deposit",
      created_at: Sat, 10 Mar 2018 18:47:43 UTC +00:00,
      updated_at: Sat, 10 Mar 2018 18:47:43 UTC +00:00>,
     #<Transaction:0x00007f9b3d0b3fa8
      id: 7,
      user_id: 1,
      amount_cents: 1200,
      amount_currency: "USD",
      category: "withdraw",
      created_at: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 02:22:42 UTC +00:00,
      updated_at: Tue, 06 Mar 2018 18:48:20 UTC +00:00>]
```

it is printing out, what I believe to be the correct information, up until the test attempts to `count` the transactions by their `category: 'deposit'`. Then I get this error message:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: deposit: SELECT COUNT(deposit) FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."user_id" = ? AND "transactions"."amount_currency" = ?`

EDITED FOR MORE INFO

Comment: are you trying to sum the deposit column? or are you counting how many records there are?

Comment: I am trying to count how many deposit transactions were made as opposed to other types of transactions.

Comment: Who wrote this test? Is this some external constraint that you have to satisfy? If it is then `one_day` is either return the wrong thing or you're supposed to have a `:deposit` column. Altering `count`'s behavior is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @muistooshort If requirements change and now they want 'withdraws', 'refunds', etc. I don't think making a new column for every one of those is a good idea. I don't think altering `count`'s behavior is a good idea either, but I am also unsure how to get count(:deposit) to get the count of all the transactions with the category of deposit. perhaps you have a better way of going about it?

Comment: The better way of going about it would, IMO, be to seek clarification from whoever is making you pass this specific test. Bring up your concerns, they are valid.

Comment: @wu_who I see you updated the post is there some issue with my answer because given what you posted this will do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

**Some Assumptions Were Made in the Writing of this answer and modifications may be made based on updated specifications**

Overriding `count` is a bad idea because others who view or use your code will have no idea that this is not the count they know and understand.
Instead consider creating a scope for this like

```
class FinancialSummary < ApplicationRecord
  scope :one_day, ->(user:,currency:) { where(user: user, currency: currency) }  #clearly already a scope
  scope :transaction_type, ->(transaction_type:) { where(category: transaction_type) }
end
```

then the test becomes

```
subject = FinancialSummary.one_day(user: user, currency: :usd)
expect(subject.transaction_type(:deposit).count).to eq(2)
```

SQL now becomes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  "transactions" 
WHERE 
  "transactions"."user_id" = ? 
   AND "transactions"."amount_currency" = "usd"
   AND "transactions"."category" = "deposit"
```

Still very understandable and easy to read without the need to destroy the count method we clearly just used.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what object the count message is being sent to because I don't know what `FinancialSummary.one_day(user: user, currency: :usd)` returns, but it seems like you are saying `count` is a method on whatever it returns, that you can't change. What does `FinancialSummary.one_day(user: user, currency: :usd).class` return?

Perhaps one solution would be to alias it on that object by adding `alias_method :count, :account_count` and then in your test calling `expect(subject.account_count(:deposit)).to eq(2)`

It would be easier if you could post the FinancialSummary#one_day method in your question.